# How to download git repository via java code

Tags: java, git, maven, github, jgit

i need to download files from git repository to directory via java code, and i have error witch my code when the download begins

```
    private void downloading() throws GitAPIException {
        String repoUrl = "url";
        String localPath = directory;
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";

        CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository()
                .setURI(repoUrl)
                .setDirectory(new File(localPath))
                .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password));
        try (Git git = cloneCommand.call()) {
            System.out.println("Repository was successfully cloned into " + localPath);
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            System.err.println("Error cloning repository: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

the full error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8935)
    at javafx.controls@21-ea/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3980)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2704)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:183)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.eclipse.jgit@6.5.0.202303070854-r/org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.<clinit>(SystemReader.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jgit@6.5.0.202303070854-r/org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.readEnvironment(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jgit@6.5.0.202303070854-r/org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jgit@6.5.0.202303070854-r/org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.init(CloneCommand.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jgit@6.5.0.202303070854-r/org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:182)
    at com.gitipi.launcher/com.gitipi.launcher.Controller.downloading(Controller.java:122)
    at com.gitipi.launcher/com.gitipi.launcher.Controller.download(Controller.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. What error?

Comment: error complains about the cloneCommand.call()

Comment: Once again, what error? Please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: added the entire error from the console to the description

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" is that class in your classpath?

Comment: there is no such class in the code

Comment: @GermanK no, but some of the code you import (jgit, from the looks of that stack trace) may depend on that.

Comment: I imported jgit through a jar file on my computer

Comment: Ok, but you need to include in the classpath its dependencies as well.

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.1.202105131744-r</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/kotge/IdeaProjects/org.eclipse.jgit-6.5.0.202303070854-r.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Don't use system scope, let maven do its job and download what you need.